# Syncing tables one-way but different tables in different directions

Tags: mariadb

I have never worked with multiple servers syncing before. I am working on a project that will require multiple MariaDB servers to sync specific tables. Each table will only ever be changed on one server, but each of those tables will be changed on a different server.

> Given tables A, B, C, and D:
>
> A - settings table - only updated when users change settings
>
> B, C, D - work tables - these will be updated every few seconds with work done by the individual servers.
>
> Main Server - Changes A; needs B, C, D kept up-to-date in real-time.
>
> Server 2 - Changes B; needs A kept up-to-date in real-time.
>
> Server 3 - Changes C; needs A kept up-to-date in real-time.
>
> Server 4 - Changes D; needs A kept up-to-date in real-time.

Looking at replication tutorials, I see lots of information about one-way and two-way, but I haven't been able to find anything that matches up with what I'm trying to do.

It is imperative that the data is synced in real-time as the information is time-sensitive. If the servers lose connection to each other, I still need the data to be synced as soon as the connection is restored.

The tables will all be updated by PHP code on their respective servers. The servers are all running Linux. Is this something that can be done with MariaDB by itself? Or would it be better to handle this in another way? I'd really like to avoid two-way replication of the entire database to all the servers as most of the data is unnecessary for any server but the main server and the server that created it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget having multiple machines trying to sync with each other.  Instead think about...

Plan A: Using a single server for all the work.  Then there is no syncing.

Plan B: Make use of the network to allow everybody to write to a Master, which continually replicates uni-directionally to any number of Slaves.  The slaves can be read from.

Plan C: Some form of clustering, such as Galera, so that multiple nodes are continually replicating to each other, and you can read/write to each node.

Beware in any sync or replication environment of the "critical read" scenario.  This is when a user writes a comment on a blog post, then fails to find it on the next web page.  The problem is that it has not been "sync'd" yet.

To answer your question:  There is no "sync" mechanism other than the 3 things I described.

**More**

Connection issues are not a serious problem -- There are many cloud services out there that come very close to being available 100.0% of the time.

Latency is not really a serious problem -- you would be surprised at how far away web sites are.  A thousand miles is "nothing" in the Internet today.

Minimize the *number* of round trips from the user to the web server if they are far apart.  And minimize the *number* of database calls between the front end and the database.  Note that it is beneficial to put the web server near the client in one case and near the database in the other case.

In a Master-Slave setup, a few gigabytes per day is a reasonable cap on traffic.  How much traffic are you talking about?

Comment: Hmm... That was what I was afraid of hearing. Forgot to mention that these servers are going to be in geographically distinct locations and I wanted to do this to help alleviate any latency or connection issues. Seemed to me it would be better to do some sort of replication than have my worker threads sit and wait for a connection to be available to the main database server again. As I'm expecting gigabytes of data to build up in each server's individual table, I didn't want to have to replicate to all of them.

Comment: I added comments to address connection and latency.

Comment: Each worker thread should write 8640 rows to the database every day. I expect to have thousands of these on each server. Each row consists of a bigint id, a Decimal(5,1), a timestamp, and 2 INTs. Doing the math based on what I've got in my work table right now, it looks like I'd be transferring about 126 KB for a thousand threads every 5 seconds. Maybe writing to the main database from the workers isn't such a bad idea after all...

Comment: So, once every 10 seconds, a thread connects, does one insert, and disconnects?  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  How many servers?
  How many connections total?  Do you have SSDs?

Comment: Correct, except every 5 seconds. I will be running on SSDs. I'm still in the development process. I have a proof-of-concept running on a single server. My initial roll-out, I plan to have 6 servers in total (the main server and 5 workers). I expect these servers to be making thousands of transactions every 5 seconds. My reasoning behind the initial question was that rather than making a connection, running an insert, and closing the connection over the internet that often, I would do it all on the local server then move it to the main server.

Comment: I need more info on the whole system.  What data is coming into the workers?  Is it like sensor readings?  Is there some way to get the "thousands" of 1-row inserts turned into a few multi-row inserts?  This will be needed for scaling.  And it is _probably_ easier to achieve in the workers than in MySQL.  For MySQL tips, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table

Comment: Sorry, Rick, for disappearing on you. I fell off this project for a while. I don't want to give away too much of what I'm doing as I believe it's a fairly unique product. It's similar to sensor readings in that the data will be arriving one result at a time and can't be processed any faster than that. I've actually been getting into Node JS development and started this project again from scratch. I plan to handle the queuing of inserts in the code if connectivity is lost to the main database server. Thanks for your insight. You definitely helped steer me around to my final conclusion.